# WatchOS App Test Flight

Tags: swift, app-store-connect, apple-watch, watchos-2

So I uploaded my first watchOS-App, but i have no clue how to test it on my apple watch (not the simulator, but on the actual watch)

I dont see anything on itunesconnect after successfully uploading it. What's next?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [TestFlight beta testing overview](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devdc42b26b8) guide. All you have to do is install the free `TestFlight` app from `AppStore`, redeem the `TestFlight` invitation there and install both the `iOS` and `watchOS` apps from inside the `TestFlight` app.

Comment: there is no section on `TestFlight` that shows watchOS build, neither in Xcode @Dávid Pásztor