# How to distribute standalone watchOS application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos

I am currently working on stand along `watchOS` application. It work fine on both simulator and testing device. Now I need to send the build for testing and after archive it not showing any option to upload build to `test flight` or `Transporter` app via ipa.

List of Question that have same issue and no accepted answer is given.

1. [standalone watchOs app need to distributeit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66720674/standalone-watchos-app-need-to-distribute-it)
2. [WatchOS App Test Flight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494913/watchos-app-test-flight)
3. [How can I test a standalone watchOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59780149/how-can-i-test-a-standalone-watchos-application)

Here's the screenshot of the screen that appears when I click on "Distribute App" button after Archiving:

[image]

I have followed the usual steps for distributing an iOS app to TestFlight, but it seems like the option to select TestFlight or ipa file is missing for watchOS apps.

Comment: I am having the same issue with Xcode 15.